# C# Only part of a ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory request was completed

Tags: c#

when ever I run my application I get the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception'
>   occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
>        Additional information: Only part of a ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory request was completed

And here is the code where it crashes, crashes on the last line:

```
SHDXOverlay.ChildControls.Add(ctrlCrosshair);
SHDXOverlay.ChildControls.Add(ctrlRadar);
SHDXOverlay.ChildControls.Add(windowMenu);
SHDXOverlay.ChildControls.Add(windowGraphs);
SHDXOverlay.ChildControls.Add(windowSpectators);
SHDXOverlay.ChildControls.Add(windowBots);
SHDXOverlay.ChildControls.Add(cursor);
PrintInfo("> Running overlay");
Application.Run(SHDXOverlay);
```

Comment: This indicates that at some level your code is calling  into `WriteProcessMemory` or `ReadProcessMemory` with - most likely - an invalid address. Is any of your code making these calls that's not shown here? What is `SHDXOverlay` for instance?

Comment: SHAXoverlay is from an instance, and that i got from a lib.

Answer (score 0):

When `Application.Run()` is called all the functionality for your overlay starts executing.  Subsequently it is making calls to `ReadProcessMemory()`.  These calls take a size in bytes to read, if your call to `ReadProcessMemory()` cannot read a portion or all of this memory, it will produce this error.  Essentially ReadProcessMemory() is failing and you need to investigate why, the most likely culprit is incorrect pointers or offsets.

Check [Marshal.GetLastWin32Error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getlastwin32error?view=netcore-3.1) after each call to a WINAPI function and step through the code, when you find the exact line where it occurs you can double check the pointers/offsets by comparing what you see in Cheat Engine to isolate your problem.